Can I make the link bold in markdown when sending messages using the Telegram Bot API?
I'm using the sendMessage() method to send messages in markdown mode. I tried different ways of sending a link with bold style on it but it doesn't work.
This is my markdown:
[*demo*](www.google.com)
*[demo](www.google.com)*
* [demo](www.google.com) *

Besides, bold & italic also doesn't work when combined:
_*Bold+Italic*_
*_Bold+Italic_*

I'm wondering that is it possible to do what I mentioned?

markdown is the old parse-mode, you should use MarkdownV2 if you want to style links.
For example, a normal, bold, and italic/bold link can be send like so:
Link: [Google](https://google.com)
Link: *[Google](https://google.com)*
Link: *_[Google](https://google.com)_*

Results in


It works. But it doesn't look the same when I combined bold and italic at the same time.   Why?

That's probably due to the client you are using.

You're correct. It's working when I view from the mobile app. Thank you so much!
